# Extract dates in a complex string

Tags: r, regex, date, gsub, as.date

I have a problem for extract dates in files names, in my example a have the `file.name` object:

```
file.name<- c("AZAMBUJAI002A20190518T133231_20190518T133919_T22JCM_2021_05_19_01_18_22.tif","RINCAODOSSOARES051B20210107T133231_20190518T133919_T22JSM_2021_05_19_01_18_22",
"VILAPALMA33K20181018T133231_20190518T133919_T23JCM_2020_05_19_01_18_22.tif")
```

I need to extract in a new object the specific dates: `20190518`, `20210107` and `20181018` inside in the files names. But for this a can't use `substr` because a have different lengths of areas names (`AZAMBUJAI002A`,`RINCAODOSSOARES051B` and `VILAPALMA33K`) and not to use remove letters too (a cause of numeric area id - 002, 051 and  33). The dates in the end before ".tif" separated by "_" is not useful information.

My desirable output is:

```
mydates
[1] 2019-05-18
[2] 2021-01-07
[3] 2018-10-18
```

Is there any solution to the problem described? Thanks!!

Comment: Is the relevant date always of the 'yyyymmdd' format? And always in the sequence before the first underscore?

Comment: Yes @dario date in `'yyyymmdd' format and before the first underscore is stable and inmutable.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Seeing your code would help folks see what your thought process is here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using base R functions. Works as long as the format is always "yyyymmdd" and the relevant string appears before the first underscore:

```
file.name<- c("AZAMBUJAI002A20190518T133231_20190518T133919_T22JCM_2021_05_19_01_18_22.tif",
              "RINCAODOSSOARES051B20210107T133231_20190518T133919_T22JSM_2021_05_19_01_18_22",
              "VILAPALMA33K20181018T133231_20190518T133919_T23JCM_2020_05_19_01_18_22.tif")
```

Using `gsub` twice: First (in the inner function) to get rid of everything after the first underscore, and then to extract the sequence of eight numbers (`[0-9]{8}`:

```
dates <- gsub(".*([0-9]{8}).*", "\\1", gsub("^([^_]*)_.*", "\\1", file.name))
```

Finally using `as.Date` to convert the strings to a R date object (can be re-cast to a string using `format`):

```
dates_as_actual_date <- as.Date(dates, format("%Y%m%d"))
```

`dates_as_actual_date` is a R date object and looks like this:

> [1] "2019-05-18" "2021-01-07" "2018-10-18"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to extract using regex - assume you only have year start with `20xx`

```r
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

date_string <- str_extract(file.name,
  "20\\d{2}\\[0,1][1-9]\\[0-3][1-9]")

date_string
#> [1] "20190518" "20210107" "20181018"

ymd(date_string)
#> [1] "2019-05-18" "2021-01-07" "2018-10-18"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)

ymd(gsub("(^.*_)(20[0-9]{2}_)([0-9]{2}_)([0-9]{2}_)(.*$)", 
         "\\2\\3\\4", 
         file.name))
```

`ymd` is a lubridate function that identifies YYYY-MM-DD dates, almost irrespective of the separator used.

`gsub` converts a string. The regex inside:

- (^.*_) is the first capture group. Takes anything from the beginning to an underscore.
- (20[0-9]{2}_) is the second capture group. It takes a string that starts with 20 and is followed by any two digits and an underscore.
- ([0-9]{2}_) is the third and fourth capture groups. It takes two digits followed by an underscore.
- (.*$) is the last (5th) capture group. Takes anything to the end of the string.
- "\2\3\4" returns second, third and fourth capture groups.

### EDIT:

The explanation to the code is still OK, but to retrieve the dates just after the names then the code needed is this:

```
ymd(gsub("(^.*[A-Z])(20[0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})(.*$)",
         "\\2\\3\\4", 
         file.name))
```

Comment: @Leprechault Not sure if you really want to use this. This solution does not work for the given example: It returns "[1] "2021-05-19" "2021-05-19" "2020-05-19" because the gsub expression only captures the last match...